# How to asynchronously export a JSON array after HTTP request in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I am running into a problem with asynchronously exporting a variable. I want to access the `apiData` in another file.  Currently, I am exporting an empty array for obvious reasons.  How can I do this asynchronously and get the JSON data?

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var request = require('request');

    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index', { title: 'InstaExpress' });
    });

    var apiData = [];

    router.post('/apiData', function(req, res) {
        var latitude = req.body.latitude;
        var longitude = req.body.longitude;
        var galleryURL = 'http://mobile-test-api.influentialdev.com/stream' +
     '?' + 'lat=' + latitude + '&lng=' + longitude;
        var detailURL = 'http://mobile-test-api.influentialdev.com/stream/:id';

        request(galleryURL, function(error, response, body) {
            if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                apiData = JSON.parse(body);
                res.json(apiData);
            }
        });
    });

    // I want the apiData to be exported after the asynchronous operation above:
    module.exports = {
        router: router,
        apiData: apiData
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "asynchronously export" something in node. What you *can* do is export a function that accepts a callback. Then when you execute the exported function, the async operation(s) are performed and the result is passed to the callback that the user supplied.

Comment: Is there a better way to be able to use the ```apiData``` variable in another file?  Currently, I am obtaining the latitude and longitude from the geolocation API by a submit action in a form (POST /apiData) and using them with a REST endpoint to get the JSON data.

Comment: What you could do is cache the value so that additional calls to the exported function would simply call the callback (maybe on the next tick though) with the cached value instead of making another network request.

Comment: I found a solution for my problem at least:

I created a separate file, _apiJSON.js_, with an empty array and exported it: 
`var data= [];
 module.exports = data;`.

Then I included this _apiJSON.js_ module in the above file and in the POST request callback, I pushed the JSON array values into this `data` array.  Now I have the JSON data in the `data` array.

Comment: You can do the same thing without an extra file. The problem though is that you won't know *when* that exported `apiJSON` value is "ready" to be consumed, especially if you go to do the http request to populate it and you end up getting some error resulting in the exported `apiJSON` value staying an empty array (how would anyone know an error happened and that the value won't be populated?).